# Error in uploading image target to Vuforia device database

Tags: image, upload, device, vuforia

I'm trying to add my images to Vuforia's device database, but it doesn't work.

I upload pictures but nothing happens.

Comment: Are you following Vuforia's specifications: "The file must be 8 or 24-bit PNG or JPG. A JPG file must be RGB or greyscale. Maximum image file size is 2.25MB."

Answer (score 1):

See the augmentable image, if its quality is low, recognition won't work.